# Vowpal Wabbit training and testing data formats

Tags: machine-learning, regression, vowpalwabbit

I'm trying Vowpal Wabbit and am in the process of figuring out the file formats required for training and testing. I've been following the tutorial from https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial and see that the following is the training data format:

```
0 | price:.23 sqft:.25 age:.05 2006
1 2 'second_house | price:.18 sqft:.15 age:.35 1976
0 1 0.5 'third_house | price:.53 sqft:.32 age:.87 1924
```

For the testing data, I don't have the labels or any outputs, but just the features. How would I go about writing that out? I've tried just including the features like so:

```
price:.23 sqft:.25 age:.05 2006
price:.18 sqft:.15 age:.35 1976
price:.53 sqft:.32 age:.87 1924
```

But, that gives me exceptions as it's not the proper format. I have also tried the following and all give me just 0's as results:

```
| price:.23 sqft:.25 age:.05 2006
| price:.18 sqft:.15 age:.35 1976
| price:.53 sqft:.32 age:.87 1924

0 0 0 | price:.23 sqft:.25 age:.05 2006
0 0 0 | price:.18 sqft:.15 age:.35 1976
0 0 0 | price:.53 sqft:.32 age:.87 1924
```

Anyone the format I should be aiming for, knowing only the features? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bar symbol (|) must be also in the format for predictions:

```
| price:.23 sqft:.25 age:.05 2006
| price:.18 sqft:.15 age:.35 1976
| price:.53 sqft:.32 age:.87 1924
```

If you don't include the correct labels, vw cannot compute the test loss, of course.
To get the predictions use `vw -d test_set.vw -t -p predictions.txt`. The training set in the tutorial (with three examples only) is too small to train any reasonable model.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  Easy to remember rule: think of the leftmost `|` symbol in each example line, as the separator between 1) what you want to predict (which can be empty) on the left, and 2) what is known (input features), on the right.

Comment: How do I load an existing model that I outputted while training? What I want is to use said model as well as some testing data to output the predictions to a file.

Comment: @intl As described in https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial `vw -i house.model -t -d test.data -p predictions`